# Home screen takng time to load after the application in android

Tags: android

i have an application which i have made. Once i use this application for sometime and if i press the home screen, it takes the home screen sometime to load and a progress dialog appears telling me that it's loading.

My application is not a graphics intensive application. It just parsers data from the an XML and displays.

Is is because of the coding of my application that the home screen is taking time to load?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

check your applications `OnPause()` method.

Also it might be related to the Activity freeing/closing all the stuff alocated to it.

You can watch the DBMS to see what is making it take so long to free up.

Lastly, the emulator is not the... fastest emulator. (Personally some of my apps took seconds to process in the emulator, but when on a device it finished in less than seconds.  This was just drawing onto the canvas)

Comment: i was not talking about an emulator, i was talking about my HTC desire z android 2.2 phone.

Comment: you can still use DBMS to check the logs, does this happen on the emulator? otherwise it might be device specific problem.

Comment: could you post the DBMS logs of when you press home?  The most likely suspects are 1. your device, 2. devicemanager freeing up devices.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a lot of memory, the Launcher process may need to be killed to make room.

Also on older versions of the platform (pre-2.0? something like that), the system was not very good about keeping the home activity's process around so just spending a long time elsewhere would eventually result in it being killed as other application processes are started in the background.

Look at the logcat output (adb shell logcat) to see more information about what is going on.